# test and train in same data or different data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I have data set of two classes, I used for classify it Naive Bayes classifier.
Firstly:   trained and tested classifier in same data I got:

```
Accuracy: 71.1262
False negative rate: FN/FN+TP = FN/P= 284/295 = 0.840 
False positive rate:  FP/FP+TN  =  FP/N = 93/886 = 0.104 
Sensitivity: Recall:True positive rate:  TP/TP+FN = TP/P = 0.1593
Specificity: True negative rate: TN/TN+FP = TN/N = 0.8950
Precision :  Positive Predictive Value: TP/TP+FP = 0.3357
Negative Predictive Value: TN/TN+FP = 0.7618
```

Secondly: I trained classifier in sample then tested in another sample I got:

```
Accuracy: 0.7704
False negative rate: FN/FN+TP=FN/P =147/222 = 0.662
False positive rate: FP/FP+TN= FP/N = 73/736=0.099
Sensitivity: Recall:True positive rate: TP/TP+FN=TP/P=75/222= 0.3378
Specificity: True negative rate:TN/FP+FP=TN/N= 663/736 = 0.9008
Precision :  Positive Predictive Value:TP/TP+FP= 0.5068
```

Actually when I tried with Decision tree and Neural network I got almost similar result
Is this normal result? what exactly is the problem in this data?

Comment: Your classes are clearly imbalanced, which gives you the big difference between FN and FP rates. Can you put some absolute values on these labels? Like how many positive/negative examples you have?

Comment: In first experiment: 
Data train size 1181.
Size of negative class 886.
Size of positive class 295.
Data test size 1181.
Size of negative class 886.
Size of positive class 295.

Comment: In second experiment:Data train size 1181.
Size of negative class 886.
Size of positive class 295.

Data test size 958.
Size of negative class 736.
Size of positive class 222.

Comment: Where *is* the problem? The accuracy on the test set is better than on the training; that is a fairly decent outcome.

Answer (score -1):

There can be multiple problems , ML is a constant process of experimentation and testing, and there are ways to "diagnose" your algorithms . Id suggest performing feature engineering and verify if you have skewed classes in your dataset, plotting learning curves, perform cross validation and model selection, analyze if you need feature scaling and normalization ,verify multiple regularization parameters ,etc